# Track "commands" send to WPF window by touchpad (Bamboo)

Tags: wpf, command

I just bought a touchpad wich allows drawing and using multitouch. The api is not supported fully by windows 7, so I have to rely on the build in config dialog.

The basic features are working, so if I draw something in my WPF tool, and use both fingers to do a right click, I can e.g. change the color. What I want to do now is assign other functions to special features in WPF.

Does anybody know how to find out in what way the pad communicates with the app? It works e.g. in Firefox to scroll, like it should (shown on this photo). But I do not know how to hookup the scroll event, I tried a Scrollviewer (which ignores my scroll attempts) and I also hooked up an event with the keypressed, but it does not fire (I assume the pad does not "press a key" but somehow sends the "scroll" command direclty. How can I catch that command in WPF?

Thanks a lot,
Chris

[EDIT] I got the scroll to work, but only up and down, not left and right. It was just a stupid "listbox in scrollviewer" mistake. But still not sure about commands like ZOOM in (which is working even in paint).. Which API contains such things?

[EDIT2] Funny, the zoom works in Firefox, the horizontal scrolling does not. But, in paint, the horizontal scrolling works...

[EDIT 3] Just asked in the wacom forum, lets see about vendor support reaction time...
http://forum.wacom.eu/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1939

Here is a picture of the config surface to get the idea what I am talking about: (Bamboo settings, I try to catch these commands in WPF)

[alt text http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/3751/20091008210914.jpg](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/3751/20091008210914.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=12100526-ed26-476b-8e20-69662b8546c1&displaylang=en) yet.

WPF 3.5 does not natively support multi-touch (it is coming in WPF 4.0) however the samples in that kit should get you started using the Windows7 Integration Library which access the native Win32 APIs to provide the required support (Don't worry its not real ugly:).

Comment: Thanks, the labs look interesting, but this will not work for my problem. I do not really have a multitouch display which uses the new windows 7 API (I whish I had some of these nice laptops). The Bamboo seems to recognize the multitouch by itself and translates them into "default command" like SCROLL or ZOOM. The scroll (only up and down) seems to work everywhere (seems to mimic the mouse wheel). So its more a general question, how is e.g. horizontal scrolling defined in WPF..

Comment: Ah I see now. Yeah the Bamboo driver is probably generating some Win32 messages that those applications that are responding - Paint and Firefox - are listening for. Sorry I can't read German :) but can you assign the event type to the action you are performing via that config...I have done this in a much simpler form with Wacom tablets, e.g. map Barrell click to Right mouse click. Your best bet would be to work out what type of WPF events each tablet action generates and then respond to those as required. There is some useful info hidden in the StylusButtonEventArgs, i.e if you dig into the...

Comment: source or device (I can't remember which now) you will get a Button id value (I think there is StylusButton.Id or similar hidden somewhere). Now this value is most likely going to be different for single touch, multi touch etc. even though the same event handler is being invoked. So yeah just try all the Stylus events, and Mouse events and dig into the arguments and you will somewhere find some way of identifying the different actions. In Charles Petzolds Application = Code + Markup there is a wee bit of code for catching and examining all the different events so this may help you get started.